# Ways to manage app state without using a library other than setState()

Tags: flutter

I want to learn ways to manage state without using package. Other than setState(), I need to learn other ways.

I just did setState, streamBuilder. Can anyone help me find out in addition to the above 2 ways, there are other ways to manage the state without packages?

Comment: By curiosity, why without using package?

Comment: see `ValueListenableBuilder` widget

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add [changeNotifier](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple#changenotifier), [valueNotfier](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ValueNotifier-class.html) and [inheritedWidget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InheritedWidget-class.html)

Comment: changeNotifier is to use package provider

Comment: @TtmChâu who said that.? maybe what you are referring to is the `ChangeNotifierProvider` which is different from `ChangeNotifier`.

Comment: `ChangeNotifier` is from flutter Sdk.

Comment: but if there is no provider, when calling notifyListeners(), it won't build again

Comment: do you have documentation about changeNotifier? Please for me

Comment: click the link i gave you..it is already there. It even explains what is ChangeNotifier and ChangeNotifierProvider. and for more in-depth,  check how flutter uses change notifier internally. One example is the `TextEditingController`, click on it and you'll see that it extends valueNotifier, and valueNotifier extends ChangeNotifier. I used ChangeNotifier when creating custom controller without importing provider.